# How to call a custom build tool through a batch file

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

While trying to setup the [Cap'n Proto](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto) compiler as a custom build tool in Visual Studio 2017, I came across a curious behavior, it only seems to work when called directly and not through a batch file.

What I first tried was, for each .capnp file, set the following Custom Build Tool settings:

```
Command line: "$(SolutionDir)run_capnpn.bat" compile -oc++ "%(FullPath)"
Description: Executing capnp.exe on %(Identity)...
Outputs: %(Identity).c++;%(Identity).h
```

I made the batch file because I wanted to avoid polluting my %PATH% with the capnp folder, this is what it contains:

```
@echo on
echo %*
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\GitHub\capnproto\bin\c++\src\capnp\Debug
start /wait "" capnp.exe %*
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

However, with this setup the Custom Build Tool was only called on 1 of the 5 capnp files in my solution (all 5 files had exactly the same settings). I know this because only one pair of generated files appeared and only one message appeared in my build log.

Even weirder, if I compiled again it would do the next file, and on the following compile it would do another file. In all, it would take 5 compiles (one per file) before it considered everything to be fully built and stop calling the custom build tool.

After much trial and error and some help from other programmers on Discord, I tried adding capnp.exe to my path and call it directly (instead of going through the batch file) so for each capnp fil I changed the command line setting to:

```
capnp.exe compile -oc++ "%(FullPath)"
```

and now it all builds correctly. Is it possible to call a custom build tool through a batch file? and if so how?

Comment: Why are you using `start /wait` instead of just running the command? And why is what you're running not including the command-line params to `capnp.exe` that you include in the last example (`compile -oc++`)?

Comment: @KenWhite `%*` is the list of params passed to the batch file, this contains `compile -oc++ ...`, as for `start /wait` well i wanted to return the error code from capnp.exe so i figured i had to wait for it to finish so, I put that in. I'm not a batch file expert. I'd like to re-iterate in case it wasn't clear, the problem isnt that the compilation doesnt work, it does, the problem is it only gets called on one file at a time for some unknown reason.

Comment: I suspect that reason is `start /wait`, which is why I asked why you were using it. The actual command being run is `start`, which launches the batch file. Did you try removing it and just calling the batch file directly?

Comment: @KenWhite Same behavior if I call the batch file but change `start /wait "" capnp.exe %*` to `capnp.exe %*`.